# Game in glut, figures and their sizes

Tags: glut

Just started programming with glut. I'm trying to make a little game, but I can't find away to make cube get bigger by itself and then get smaller when it hits the wall without using any buttons. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
glLoadName(CUBE);
glColor3f(0.2, 0, 1); glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(20, 0, 15, 0);
glutSolidCube(size);
if (size = 0.5)
{
    size + 0.2;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
glutSwapBuffers();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: i've tried if (as you can see), using for, scale function. but nothing works the way i want it to work